# Edge browser ignores CSS variable

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, css-variables

As you can see in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/50mqy8p1/1/
Microsoft Edge ignores `display: var(--display-var, block)` after a `display: none;` so the div is not visible. Other browsers show this correct (IE11 works based on the fallback above the var-usage).

Is there any mistake in my code? Or do you know a workaround? Google did not help me here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Edge Demo</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
      }
      .foo {
        --display-var: flex;
        background: #369;
        height: 100%;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      .make-invisible { display: none; }
      .make-visible {
        display: block;
        display: var(--display-var, block);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="foo make-invisible make-visible">I am here!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see below, it also happens if you use only one class and a media query

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Edge Demo</title>
    <style>
      .foo {
        --display-var: flex;
        display: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 320px) {
        .foo {
          display: block;
          display: var(--display-var, block);
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="foo">I am here!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What is our use-case, that let us run in this problem: 
We have a CMS where a content editor can choose when something should be visible or invisible.
Then we generate generic visibility/invisibility classes and a generic corresponding small CSS snippet that handles the visibility.
But sometimes you don't want an element to be 'block', but for example 'flex'. With this CSS-Vars trick, the design can decide what it wants the element to be as soon as it becomes visible without doing anything else.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Thanks, @Paulie_D I never thought on JSFiddle to go down ;)

Comment: @dennisvandehoef It's rare, but it does happen! It's also a convenience thing; we shouldn't have to go to another site just to be able to fully read your problem and associated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `display: none;` attribute of the `.make-invisible` class confuses Edge.

I thought updating the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of the `.make-visible` class to something like `.foo.make-visible` would make the problem go away but even then the issue persists on Edge.

The simplest solution IMO would be to remove the `.make-invisible` class from the div element because I don't see a reason why you would need to have both the `.make-invisible` and `.make-visible` classes on a single element at the same time.

**Update**

After considering your update I was able to come up with a hack that isn't too ugly. This not only gets around the issue on Edge but also doesn't affect the behavior on Chrome or FF.

What you will need to do is define the class twice with each property in an individual class like:

```
    .foo {
      display: block;
    }
    .foo {
      display: var(--display-var, block);
    }
```

Here's a working version of your demo: https://jsfiddle.net/sbr29yo6/

Comment: Thanks for your reaction @awad-maharoof, of course, it is the simplest to remove this obsolete class in this code. Sadly this is just some code to reproduce the problem. Let me check tomorrow if I can achieve it in my real code. If it is not possible I will come back with an explanation why it is not possible to remove that class ;)

Comment: Sure, do let me know. It sure is an interesting problem :)

Comment: Hi Awad Maharoof, sadly this problem also happens with only one class and media queries, which is actually more the way we use it. The first example was the most simple form of this problem was visible. I added a second example and our use case to the original post.

Comment: Hey @dennisvandehoef I've updated my answer. Lemme know how it goes :)

Comment: Thanks, even though it is not the coolest solution for my code base, it is a working solution... maybe even the only one :( in case someone has a different solution I would still like to see it :) But for today, I mark this as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you had used various classes at the same time.

Generally, there is no need to use the multiple classes at the same time.

It is also depended that every browser works differently and it is possible that Edge gives the priority to other class result in this output.

You can try to use JS to replace the class to one with another.

If there is any specific purpose to use the multiple classes then you can let us know about that.

We will try to provide further suggestions based on that requirement.

Comment: Hi @deepak, I added a second example with only one class and a media query. Which is not the simplest way to reproduce the problem, but is more like the problem I have. I also added a use case and would be really unhappy to add Javascript to all these pages to fix a CSS problem in one browser :(

Comment: @deepak What do you mean by "us" and "we"? Are you associated in some way with Microsoft Edge or the CSS Working Groups?

Comment: @TylerH, I am associated with MSDN support team.

Comment: @ dennisvandehoef, I made a test with your new code in Edge and Chrome. If you check the development tools then you can find that both browser will show you similar CSS applied with different result. In that you can notice that your css variable also applied. So at present I am thinking that this is how Edge is working in a different way then the Chrome.